# Ledger Type Update in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Promast is a sample transaction table and I want to update Proreg a sample opening balance Table.

I want to scan promast from beginning sum based on trantype and then update Proreg with the summed value.

How can this be achieved in SQL Server without using cursors.

Thanks & Regards,
Mohan

Table Name :  promast  (This is a sample transaction data)

```
Region  area    name       amount   TranType
----------------------------------------------
  01    AA      Capital      10       D
  01    AA      Capital     -20       C
  01    AA      Capital      50       D
  01    BB      Capital      80       D
  01    BB      Capital     -30       C
  01    BB      Capital      40       D
```

Table Name :   proreg  (This is maintains Balances)

```
region  area    opnamt
------------------------
  01    AA        40
  01    BB        90
```

My SQL query:

```
UPDATE proreg 
SET proreg.opNamt = proreg.OpNamt + (SELECT 
                         CASE 
                            WHEN promast.LType = 'D' 
                               THEN SUM(promast.amount)  
                            WHEN promast.LType = 'C' 
                               THEN SUM(promast.amount) 
                            END
                     FROM 
                         promast 
                     WHERE 
                         proreg.region = promast.region 
                         AND proreg.area = promast.area 
                     GROUP BY 
                         promast.LType ) 
FROM proreg
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I know this is because the query returns more than one row But want to know the best method for above

Don’t want to update like this

```
UPDATE proreg 
SET proreg.opnamt = (SELECT SUM(promast.amount) 
                     FROM promast 
                     WHERE proreg.region = promast.region 
                       AND proreg.area = promast.area 
                       AND promast.LType = 'D') 
FROM proreg
```

because if there are more types then it is cumbersome .

The command should scan all records of promast which matches proreg based on Region, area and then based on Ltype Sum and update proreg opnAmt

Comment: Look at what the inner select returns and the error message

Comment: As the debit and credit amounts are signed a simple SUM will give you the correct balance

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to sum only where the tranType equals 'D' so here is something that may help:

```
Update proreg 
SET proreg.opnamt = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN promast.LType = 'D' THEN promast.amount
                                     WHEN promast.LType = 'C' THEN promast.amount * (-1) END) 
                     FROM promast 
                     WHERE proreg.region = promast.region 
                       AND proreg.area = promast.area)
```

If the rows with `TranType` column is C are already in minus then use this:

```
Update proreg 
SET proreg.opnamt = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN promast.LType = 'D' Or promast.LType = 'C' THEN promast.amount ELSE 0 END) 
                     FROM promast 
                     WHERE proreg.region = promast.region 
                       AND proreg.area = promast.area)
```

Please test this code and give me feedback if it's working.

Comment: Thank you for giving a quick Response . I have just edited the query there was mistake while copying the query and data.

Comment: Thank you for giving a quick Response . I have just edited the query there was mistake while copying the query and data.  Your answer was
right . But as you can see from my updated query what I want to know is  when Ltype is D then it should be proreg.opnamt =  (proreg.opnamt+promast.amount)   so when D it will Add and When C it will subtract as amount is in Minus Sign

Comment: I see, one question, the value in rows with 'C' are in minus or not ? because if it's already minus then you just sum, but if it's not then you will have to write as my edit.

Comment: Thanks Tonner Maan and Michal Turczyn  I tried both your  Sql It is working as I expected. Thanks once again for clearing my doubt

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
update reg set opnamt = opnamt + (select sum(amount) from @promast
                                  where region = reg.region 
                                    and area = reg.area 
                                    and LType in ('C', 'D'))
from @proreg reg
```